# What's the reasoning for nginx defaulting to error 503 when a rate limit applies instead of error 429?

Tags: http, nginx

The [documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#rate-limiting) says:

- `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-connections`: number of concurrent connections allowed from a single IP address. A 503 error is returned when exceeding this limit.
- `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rps`: number of requests accepted from a given IP each second. The burst limit is set to this limit multiplied by the burst multiplier, the default multiplier is 5. When clients exceed this limit, `limit-req-status-code` default: 503 is returned.

In case of request limits, the HTTP error code [can de overridden](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#limit-req-status-code), though.

The [HTTP spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429) says:

> The `HTTP 429 Too Many Requests` response status code indicates the user has sent too many requests in a given amount of time ("rate limiting").

Question: why did nginx decide to go with HTTP 503 in first place? It looks like HTTP 429 is the response code that describes the issue best.

Comment: Just to frame the conversation correctly, this is not "Nginx" that you're asking about, it's the Ingress-NGINX Controller for Kubernetes

Comment: you're right, that's the scope where I stumbled upon, but the same applies to bare nginx as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recently I found [this discussion thread](https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/#comment-6126960058), citing @niels-keurentjes

> They have different semantics. 503 implies a server error (5xx range), specifically in this case a backend server being protected from overloading. The client was never able to predict this from happening, so it's not a client error. 503 means "I would have loved to help you, but can't because the service is unavailable".

> 429 however is a client error (4xx range) occurring because the client is exceeding a clearly defined and specified restriction. 429 therefore means "I will not help you because you made a mistake in addressing me".

> They are VERY different errors. And, unless specified, the basic assumption is that servers have no predefined rate limits, and therefore exceeding one is the server's cause. 503 is as such the correct and best default.

> 429 may frequently be the intended answer from rate limiting, but only if the client should/could have known better. That's the difference between a 4xx and 5xx.

I think he has a fair point.

Answer (score 3):

@Marc Wittke gave an excellent answer with the cited discussion thread.

I will give a practical answer as a consumer of an API or endpoint:

503 gives the consumer of an API no indication what is wrong and is left guessing. Is the service unavailable because of something I cannot control (something else caused the unavailable service) or something I can control (the rate of requests).

429 is on point and describes the solution to the problem with a single status code: Send fewer request. If you want a well designed self-documenting API, this is the correct answer.

You can redefine nginx behavior with this line in the server block configuration (see [official nginx blog post](https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/)):

```
limit_req_status 429;
```